# XAudio2 tutorial - Seperate thread and asynchronous reads?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, asynchronous, xaudio2

I've used this XAudio2 streaming tutorial in the past with success in creating a program to stream and play audio from disk (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415791(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now that I am reworking the code, something odd stands out to me. They create a separate thread to read the audio data in small chunks from file and submit those chunks to the voice buffer. Great, now the main thread can do whatever it needs while the audio plays, but why also use asynchronous file reads in the streaming thread? As far as I can tell, a file read is performed at each loop iteration and the thread immediately waits until the chunk is fully read before submitting it to the voice buffer.

Is there an advantage to what they are doing or is it unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, using ReadFile then immediately going to GetOverlappedResult seems more than a bit odd. Personally I prefer ReadFileEx with an APC and having my message loop built around MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx so that it performs an alertable wait at the same time as notifying that messages are ready. That way a second thread isn't even needed for this kind of I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the XAudio2 sample code uses 'asynchronous' rather than 'blocking' I/O is best-practice. The reason it's done in a 'worker thread' is mostly for simplicity since in a game typically the audio is handled by it's own thread to avoid glitches and keeping the render/update loop distinct.

You could handle the async/submit as part of your `Update` loop, but only if you were sure it would always get processed quickly enough to avoid the glitches. This is in fact the approach I took with the latest legacy DirectX SDK version of the XAudio2 streaming sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2/XAudio2AsyncStream)

> A fancier implementation could have used `ReadFileEx`, but the worker-thread approach was simpler. Also due to some quirks of how API partitioning was implemented back in Windows 8, `ReadFileEx` was not supported on the Windows Store platform / Windows phone 8 / UWP so the tutorials/samples avoided it to keep from pointing you in a direction that wasn't applicable to all the Microsoft platforms. FWIW, `ReadFileEx` and `WriteFileEx` got added back to UWP in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (14393).

Note there are some quirks in the event waiting with overlapped I/O in how `ERROR_IO_PENDING` scenarios are handled. This is improved & simplified in Windows 8 or later by the `GetOverlappedResultEx` function. For my wave bank reader in [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio), I used this pattern to build for both older and newer platforms:

```
bool wait = false;
if( !ReadFile( hFile.get(), &m_data, sizeof( m_data ), nullptr, &request ) )
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError();

    if ( error != ERROR_IO_PENDING )
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( error );

    wait = true;
}

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
result = GetOverlappedResultEx( hFile.get(), &request, &bytes, INFINITE, FALSE );
#else
if ( wait )
    (void)WaitForSingleObject( m_event.get(), INFINITE );

result = GetOverlappedResult( hFile.get(), &request, &bytes, FALSE );
#endif

if ( !result || ( bytes != sizeof( m_data ) ) )
{
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( GetLastError() );
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting way of handling streaming audio. Shortly before your response, I was able to get it working with synchronous file reads in the worker thread with no issue, so I guess it's fine either way, just redundant in the tutorial. With different methods of implementation (single thread asynchronous / multi-thread synchronous), the benefits and drawbacks seem more clear to me.

Comment: The code above is intended to be called from a 'audio worker thread' so it can block waiting on the load. It's probably not a good idea to do it from your main thread unless that's all you are doing. Note that this particular code is used in the [WaveBank](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2/XAudio2WaveBank) sample. It's not actually *streaming* code, but it does use async I/O.

Comment: Sounds good. I think this'll be something I'll dig deeper into if my program demands it, but I believe I have the answers I need for now.